# React Router doesn't intercept an HTTP/S request

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My understanding of React Router is that once the single page is bootstrapped on the client side, all subsequent calls to routes don't go to the server. They are intercepted by React Router. But why does my app always make a HTTP request to the server? Despite having the React Router code? When I see Networks on the browser dev tools, I always see a network request being made for each "react routed" route.

I tested the app by first starting the server, then delivering the index file across and then stopping the server after the client side rendering was complete. I then tried to access another route such as "/contactus" from the client side app,  but the request seems to go to the server (which is now not running), and the hence the client side doesn't get any file and the browser goes blank. My understanding was that React Router intercepts all API calls once the client side bootstrapping of the app is done.

I then modified my server side code by doing a app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../dist", "landing_page.html"));
});

Now the app works. But this defeats the whole purpose of React Router as all requests are going to the server.
So what is React Router then? Is it only for routing and not for interception? Is there any variant of React Router that intercepts the requests? Or do I use something like a history API?
This is my code.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
 
} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {


  render() {
      return (
      <Router>
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <div className="banner">
                <Banner />
              </div>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/cloudautomation">
              <div style={{ position: "absolute", top: "15%", zIndex: "-1" }}>
                <CloudAutomation />
              </div>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/marketingautomation">
              <div style={{ position: "absolute", top: "15%", zIndex: "-1" }}>
                <MarketingAutomation />
              </div>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/contactus">
              <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <ContactUs />
              </div>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("main"));
```

Comment: react-router is for navigation, not interception requests

Comment: if you want intercept you should use `axios` package

Comment: @KetZoomer. Whats the difference between navigation and interception. Could you give me an example.

Comment: Look at Kseikyo's answer

Answer (score 1):

React-router-dom is usually used to prevent your page from reloading every asset when routing through your own website, hence, providing that SPA experience.

If you are looking to intercept requests, you can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Example from their own docs:

```js
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Comment: "React-router-dom is used to prevent your page reloading when routing through your own website" - in reference to this sentence - React Router Dom does load the page, because each API call goes to the server, gets an index file and reloads the page. Whilst reloading, the React Router Dom code is read, and the appropriate React component rendered. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SteveMaxwell I guess you are mixing frontend and backend code. React is used to create your frontend and request data from your backend, each of these are running separatedly. From what you told me, you are trying to serve an static HTML file from the server for React to use it?

Comment: Yes. I am serving an HTML page with a bundled js file. The bundled js has been created by webpack. Multiple react components are part of the bundle. The bundle is interpreted in the client side and the DOM constructed. I am a python developer who has just turned to react. I was watching a youtube video by netninja where has says that react router intercepts all requests.

Comment: If you are just starting on React, you can use tools like [CRA](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)  or Next.js to handle the bundling and serving for you. Unless serving your own HTML is a project requirement, I wouldn't serve it myself as it's much harder and doesn't scale well. The CRA link will probably answer your questions about your project requirements and which tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat correct.

React-router will "intercept", so to speak, any calls and subsequently perform the client side routing. There wouldn't be a server call for every request. However, certain scenarios will trigger a call to the server and that (usually) results in the server responding with the index.js file for all (usually) the paths requested. An example is if you manually refresh the page. And in your example, you appear to be doing so in that you don't seem to be using "Links" but instead typing in the paths in the address bar.

If you add the below;

```
<Link to='/'>Banner</Link>
<Link to='/cloudautomation'>Cloud Automation</Link>
<Link to='/marketingautomation'>Marketing automation</Link>
<Link to='/contactus'>Contact us </Link>
```

between Router and Switch at the beginning, you will notice that there aren't any server calls triggered. You can also use a single Switch component for all the routes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misconception about what a client side router does. `React-router` does not intercept any requests initiated by the web browser.

What `react-router` does is:

- Use the `history` of the page (current location, url, query string, state etc) to decide what content should be rendered. In effect, with `react-router`, the location of the page is just another source of `state` (along with component props/state, react context or any other state manager). It is like **reading the state of a component** to decide what to render.
- Provide certain components (like `<Link />`) who *mimic* anchors (`<a href="..." />`). Those components **do not** initiate a request (as it seems you assume) that is going to be intercepted by `react-router`. Those components have the behavior of directly manipulating the `history` object of the page (with javascript of course). In effect they **set the state of the history** (pretty similar to calling setState to alter the state of a component) and nothing more. They add or replace history points in the history object. No request here to be intercepted. Since the history of the page is a *state source* when the history changes, immediately a new rerender is initiated and the new corresponding component is rendered (maybe another "page" component, or maybe another filter in a query string or whatever you want to do with that state).
- Provide certain hook functions (like `useNavigate()`) to give the user to manually *navigate* to another location. As is the case with the components, those hooks do not initiate any request to the server, they are just tools to manipulate the state manually.

As you see, using a client side router does not, in any way, intercept any request, because there is no request in the first place to intercept.

As far as concering your code, it is not clear how you navigate from one page to another. I don't see any `<Link />` component anywhere. If you use `<Link />` there should not be any problem. The page should not reload. But if you use `<a />` tags, then of course those tags will trigger a request to the server because that is the default behavior of such a tag when clicked.